# How does loss function affect backpropogation?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, backpropagation

So I know that backpropogation is a way to improve the model, and is done via adjusting the weights and biases. However I don't understand how loss function facilitates the backpropogation.

Like the loss functions that I have encountered so far like MSE, MAE, BCE, all output a single value. Meanwhile, weights and biases are a multi-dimensional vector with many values. So how does the single value loss function result work in a way that it's capable of adjusting those many weights and values?

Comment: backpropagation is just an efficient way of twiddling each knob (ie weight) and seeing whether it reduces or increases your overall error.

Comment: Oh ok, I can picture the concept. So like I've seen cases where the overall error is a sum of multiple errors, like a sum of BCE and MAE. So is that the best way to twiddle the knobs? 

Like wouldn't a better way be to separate the errors by doing it sequentially (i.e. BCE then MAE)? That way it can focus on one error, then move on to the next.